# Sequelize - Many to Many relationship Model A is not associated to Model B

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two Entities: TrainingDay and Exercise which are in a many to many relationship. For the implementation of the relationship I have oriented myself on the following link: https://medium.com/@the_ozmic/how-to-create-many-to-many-relationship-using-sequelize-orm-postgres-on-express-677753a3edb5.
Unfortunately, I get the following error: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: TrainingDays is not associated to Exercises!`

**Exercises.js**

```
//jshint esversion:6

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const database = require('../database.js');
const TrainingDays = require('./TrainingDays.js');

const Exercises = database.define('Exercises', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.STRING
});

// TODO: not shure why I have to wrap Exercise.belongsToMany... into Exercise.associate = function(models) {...
Exercises.associate = function(models) {
  Exercises.belongsToMany(models.TrainingDays, {
    through: 'ExerciseTrainingDays',
    as: 'trainingDays',
    foreignKey: 'exerciseId'
  });
};


module.exports = Exercises;
```

**TrainingDay.js**

```
//jshint esversion:6

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const database = require('../database.js');
const TrainingPlans = require('./TrainingPlans.js');
const Exercises = require('./Exercises.js');

const TrainingDays = database.define('TrainingDays', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  date: Sequelize.DATE,
  muscleGroup: Sequelize.STRING
});



TrainingDays.associate= function(models){
  TrainingDays.belongsTo(models.TrainingPlans);
  TrainingDays.belongsToMany(models.Exercises, {
    through: 'ExerciseTrainingDays',
    as: 'exercises',
    foreignKey: 'trainingDayId'
  });
};


module.exports = TrainingDays;
```

Here is the Join Entity: 
**ExerciseTrainingDays.js**

```
//jshint esversion:6

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const database = require('../database.js');

const ExerciseTrainingDays = database.define('ExerciseTrainingDays', {
  ExerciseId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'Exercises',
      key: 'id'
    }
  },
  TrainingDayId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: 'TrainingDays',
      key: 'id'
    }
  }
});

module.exports = ExerciseTrainingDays;
```

I use the following code for testing:

```
//jshint esversion:6


const TrainingPlans = require('./models/TrainingPlans.js');
const TrainingDays = require('./models/TrainingDays.js');
const Exercises = require('./models/Exercises.js');
const Sets = require('./models/Sets.js');
const ExerciseTrainingDays = require('./models/ExerciseTrainingDays.js');
const database = require('./database.js');

database.sync();


TrainingPlans.findAll().then(trainingPlans => {
  console.log("All trainingPlans:", JSON.stringify(trainingPlans, null, 4));
});

TrainingDays.findAll().then(trainingDays => {
  console.log("All trainingDays:", JSON.stringify(trainingDays, null, 4));
});

Exercises.findAll().then(exercises => {
  console.log("All exercises:", JSON.stringify(exercises, null, 4));
});

Exercises.findAll({
  include:[{
    model: TrainingDays,
    where: {id : 1000}}]
}).then(exercise => {
  console.log("All exercises:", JSON.stringify(exercise, null, 4));
});
```

After the call of `Exercises.findAll({ include:[{…` I get the described error. The other queries work in a proper way. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Try adding this as: "'trainingDays', foreignKey: 'exerciseId'" in the include.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, just adding the mentioned lines did not help, I still get the same error message.